# Is there a limit on the number of Minor Upgrades I can release?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

We have just started using InstallShield and I am told that we can only have a maximum of 15 Minor Upgrades before we have to do a Major Upgrade. I have scanned the documentation and have not found anything to confirm this. Does anyone know if this is the case or not?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a company policy, rather than a technological limitation?

Comment: Never heard of this limitation. These are the only ones I know http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Guys. I am not sure, it was in some documentation left by our departing CTO, it may well have been his personal policy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guidance stems from two things. First, the maximum depth of a feature in the feature tree is 16, as documented in [Feature Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368585.aspx)'s info on the `Feature_Parent` column. Second, during a minor upgrade the normal feature selection dialogs are not shown, so you have to find another way to install a feature. Under `Attributes`, the value `msidbFeatureAttributesFollowParent` is one such way.

If you build your feature tree inefficiently, always adding a child feature of your latest added feature, you will quickly hit the depth limit. If you're smart about this, or are just replacing files instead of adding new ones, you can go much longer. That said, I would still recommend flattening your test matrix every so often.

InstallShield's QuickPatch projects would create the deep feature tree, at least before the introduction of the option to [streamline](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/StreamliningQP.htm) them (see the note), but they create minor upgrade *patches* instead of minor upgrade *packages*. Perhaps the note is just somewhat confused or obsolete.

Comment: My personal opinion is that 99% of companies are best served by major upgrades and have no need of minor upgrades / patches in the first place.  If I was new to InstallShield I would master the Major Upgrade story first and only look at the others if there is a valid business need.

Comment: How does QuickPatch actually work? Normal patching is just a delivery mechanism for a normal MSI upgrade, what is the technical basis of QuickPatch?

Comment: @Glytzhkof Questions should usually be asked on questions, but as a high level overview, the QuickPatch project type offers limited design capabilities, and abstracts the process of building the minor upgrade image. It outputs just the patch from your previous image or images to the upgraded image. Its original design comes from a pre-MSI 2.0 era when patches were not even as, um, well-behaved as they are now.

Comment: I see, thanks for the overview. I ask as a comment because questions on those kinds of topics tend to be closed immediately.